# my django form is not saving the inputs in the admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How do I style my django form to look like my frontend template originally was? I created my django form and it does not look good and it is not saving the inputs in the admin panel either. Could you tell me what I need to add in the code or what I'm doing wrong?

models.py

```
class Complaints(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
highpriority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views.py:

```
class ComplaintCreate(CreateView):
    model = Complaints
    form = ComplaintForm
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('New')
    template_name = 'new.html'
```

template:

```
</div>

    <!-- Middle Container -->
    <div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">New Complaint</h1>

        <form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-control col-lg-10 comp-title-field"> {{form.title}} </div>
            <p class="desc">Description</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary preview-btn">Preview</button>
            <div class="Descr"> {{form.description}} </div>
            <button type="file" name="myfile" class="btn btn-secondary attach-btn"><i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> Attachment</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary save-btn" value="submit"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

forms.py

```
class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Complaints
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['user']
```

Also the site looks like this atm:
[image]

How do I make it look like this?:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think just styling is required for your page.
try and play with it.Add 
 tags if contents are colliding.

```
.....
.....
<br>
<br>
<button type="file" name="myfile" class="btn btn-secondary attach-btn"><i 
class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> Attachment</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary save-btn"value="submit"> 
<i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get Indentation Error ?? You wrote Meta class at the begging of the line.

That will be like this:

```
class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Complaints
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

Comment: No, it got this way over here... in the code its correct

Answer (score 0):

if using bootstrap
you can use the `django-crispy-forms` this is a package you can install it and only add filter in form like this `{{form|crispy}}` and all form convert to bootstrap

how use this package >>

Install latest stable version into your python environment using pip:

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

Once installed add `crispy_forms` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (

    'crispy_forms',
)
```

and in settings.py add :

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Finally, you can use it in the template by

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

and add filter in your form like this

```
{{form|crispy}}
```

But do not forget to have a bootstrap installed